# When choosing check box in a div it's animate back

Tags: jquery

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.drop_down_label').animate({ height: 'toggle' });
 });
```

I have a div '.drop_down_label' that contains check boxes, when I animate the div like so it's working ok

but if i check some check box it's animate back.

How can i avoid this?

My goal is click-->animate '.drop_down_label' --> **check some check boxes**-->then when clicking on **any element in the page**

cause the '.drop_down_label' to **animate back**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way [HTML events work](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) is that they bubble up.  Clicking on a checkbox inside a div will trigger the div's click event too.

Attach a click handler to the checkboxes that does the following:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]", ".selector").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

for the second half of clicking any element on the page (though I think you mean any element *outside* the `.selector` div), this *should* work (untested).

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.drop_down_label').animate({ height: 'toggle' });
    $(document).one('click', function(e) {
        $(this).children('.drop_down_label').animate({ height: 'toggle' });
    })
})
```

Comment: Yeah sorry i meant any element outside the .selector div , Also what is e.stopPropagation()? it's can be return false also? and:) what means the '$(document).one()' what is one function?

Comment: The first click function that let me check check boxes work but click out side this selector doesn't animate the check boxes div up, Cant i choose all other divs which triggers this animate except the one that is open now and just animate them?

Comment: you have to walk up the tree to find that your click's target isn't within your selector.  here is an example of that.  http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/hurQm/1/